# Controller 'accordion', required by directive 'accordionGroup', can't be found error in ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui-bootstrap for accordian, I have included ui.bootstrap in app.js. I am getting this error - 
Controller 'accordion', required by directive 'accordionGroup', can't be found!

Here is the code I am using -

```
    <accordian close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group is-open="false" heading="Requests">
        <div ng-repeat="">
        < accordion-group heading="">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>H</th>
                  <th>C</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="" ng-init="inner=$index">
                   <td>{{}}</td>
                   <td>{{}}</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
      </accordion-group>
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
 </accordian>
```

Comment: You've opened two accordion-group directives, one inside the other. Don't do that

Comment: Make a spelling mistake. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<accordian close-others="oneAtATime">
        ^
You got a typo here
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have not made any syntax/spelling mistakes. If you still get the same error, then probably it has something to do with your dependencies. Make sure you have included the right files.

And for ui-bootstrap dependency, "accordion" is a template, so you have to include src = "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" and not "ui-bootstrap.js". Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I see from the sample code you posted there are some decrependacies in the spelling of your element tags, accordion and accordian have you checked these? Is that not the possble issue here? I'm using accordion without any issues myself in my current project.